# Multiple fragment listeners in one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have this one Activity, and I need to send data from it to two different fragments. Is there a way to set this up?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements{ FragmentOne.OnEventListener, fragmentTwo.OnEventListener {
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

So basically I am trying to use one interface and I have all the other methods set up in my two fragments and everything works as intended for fragmentOne. I am just trying to figure out how to make the same listener and interface work for the second interface as well. Is there a way to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not seeing your `Fragment` code and `interface` code here.

Comment: Activity can implement 2 or more interfaces. So Fragment count is not neccessary. If your Fragments have same Listeners you should have variable about which Fragments data changed. Show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, "the same listener and interface", so you don't need to hold two instances of the interface, but just make the mainActivity implements the same one. (if it's not the case post your interface and fragments code).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are semi-following the android fragment tutorial? Please share the rest of your code.

It should work as long as your activity is correctly implementing both interfaces. Java cannot extend multiple classes but can implement multiple interfaces. However your activity must provide implementation for both of the onEventListeners.